# cant use animateCamera method from MapView component

Tags: react-native-maps

I'm on version 0.22.1 on react-native-maps, when i try to use the new `animateCamera` method from the MapView component, it complains that it is undefined and not a function, but the deprecated `animateToRegion` method still works.

Answer (score 0):

animateCamera is working. I already used in my project and there's no problem.

code example:

```
const mapRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
   if (mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current.animateCamera({
          center: {latitude, longitude},
        });
      }
},[currentPosition]);

<MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        style={styles.mapContainer}
        initialRegion={{
           ...currentPosition,
           latitudeDelta: 0.001,
           longitudeDelta: 0.001,
        }}
     >
        <Marker coordinate={currentPosition} />
</MapView
```